Number of irreducible polynomials of degree at most n over a finite field
We know that the number $N(n,q)$ of  irreducible polynomials of degree $n$
over the ﬁnite ﬁeld $\mathbb{F}_q$
is given by Gauss’s formula
$$N(n,q)=\frac{q-1}{n} \sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)q^d.$$
The number  $M(n,q)$ of  irreducible polynomials of degree at most $n$
over the ﬁnite ﬁeld $\mathbb{F}_q$  should be $M(n,q)= \sum_{k=1}^n N(k,q)$. Is there a nicer (shorter) formula for
$M(n,q)$ as well as a sharp upper bound on it?
